# UITableView jumps to the top when a cell is deleted and then goes back to his position

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, uitableview, rubymotion

I'm trying to code a feed so it's just a basic UITableView with one row per section and as many sections as posts.
If I select a cell the tableView displays a cell in the row 1 in the same section than the selected cell, and if I re-select the cell or scroll the tableView the row 1 is deleted.

The problem is that if i select the first cell and then scroll to the bottom (like a pull to refresh), the tableView scroll while the animation of the deleting cell is done then at the end of the animation jumps to the top of the screen and then return where he was.

I don't know if that was clear.

Here's my scrollViewDidScroll

```
def scrollViewDidScroll(scroll_view)
    return if @can_scroll_comments
    hide_comments unless @comment_triggered_for == -1
  end

  def hide_comments
    feed_view = layout.get(:feed_view)

    section = @comment_triggered_for
    @comment_triggered_for = -1
    feed_view.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath.indexPathForRow(1, inSection: section)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade)
  end
```

in objective-c it should be something like

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_can_scroll_comments) {
        return ;
    }
    if (_comment_triggered_for != -1) {
        [self hide_comments];
    }
}

- (void)hide_comments: {
    section = _comment_triggered_for
    _comment_triggered_for = -1
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: you can use begin update, stop update of uitableview

Comment: I tried with the begin & end updates but it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Below link will help you out : [tabeview jumping on endupdate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917923/uitableview-jumping-to-top-on-endupdates-while-typing-inside-a-cell-on-ios-8-aut/38582892#38582892)