# UITableView jumps after calling reloadSections:withRowAnimation:

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I need to expand/collapse a section of `UITableView`. I do this by calling `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` and returning `0` from `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` if the section is supposed to be collapsed.

It works fine except for one case. If the table view is scrolled all the way down and content size decreases after collapse, it ends up being scrolled beyond maximum offset.
Now instead of scrolling in place with animation it just snaps there, which looks ugly:

[image]

Here's what I have tried:

1. Wrapping `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` in `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates`:

   ```
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
   tableView.endUpdates()
   ```

   That did not help.
2. Wrapping `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` in `CATransaction` with completion block, calculating the scroll distance within it and scrolling table view with animation:

   ```
   CATransaction.begin()
   CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
       // tableView.contentSize is incorrect at this point
       let newContentOffset = ... // calculated value is not correct
       tableView.setContentOffset(newContentOffset, animated: true)
   }

   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
   tableView.endUpdates()
   CATransaction.commit()
   ```

How do I make sure the table view does not jump?

Comment: I think I am also sort of facing same issue. The gif is sort of hard to comprehend what you saying. Any way you can create a short clip maybe? Would give much clear idea.

Comment: @rohan-patel replaced the demo, this one should demonstrate the problem better.

Comment: [UITableView jumping to top on endUpdates while typing inside a cell on iOS 8 auto height](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28917923/2301450)

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue when using custom headers in collapsible sections. I did solve it by implementing.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

Comment: Fixed the issue for me!